# How to load the same js.erb file with render tag in multiple html.erb files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render, partial

I have 3 JS functions and I use Rails `render` inside each of them to load my Rails partials based on the conditions inside the JS functions.

I knew that I can't put these functions inside assets JS because `render` will not working in assets.

I have many static pages and what I want now is, make that 3 JS functions available to all my static pages.

My StaticPagesController as follows:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def faq
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

**What I've tried but didn't worked**

1. I put all the JS functions inside `views/static_pages/static_pages.js.erb`
2. I put all the JS functions inside `views/layouts/application.js.erb`
3. I put all the JS functions inside `views/shared/static_pages.js.erb`
4. I put all the JS functions inside `views/application/application.js.erb`
5. I put all the JS functions inside `public/application.js.erb`

What should I do? Am I missing something?

**Note**:
I'm using asset pipeline.

Comment: What is your `JS functions` and how did you put it to your `erb` files?

Comment: @HieuPham my JS functions will check which device is user currently using. If desktop, show desktop_nav partial, if tablet, show tablet_nav partial, if phone, show phone_nav partial. This is the JS library that I'm using and put inside assets/javascripts: https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile

Comment: Could you update what you did/what is the error?, because just base on your question, I can't find out any clue?

Comment: have you tried putting your partials on the views folder?